# Target a child link in a nav menu

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a dropdown nav for mobile and I'm using an active class to hide and show submenus via CSS. The code below works for the initial list item, but closes the parent as soon I try and open a child list item in the submenu (which uses the same structure and classes)

**What I think is happening**

I think the issue is that as soon as I click inside the parent `li` the js registers the click event and closes via the toggle.

**Problem**

So how do I get the javascript to select the child link and attach the click event to that, but still add the active class to the parent `li` item so the CSS cascades through the submenus?

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li class="menu-item-has-children nav-level-0">
    <a class="#">Child link</a>
    <ul class="submenu"></ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item-has-children nav-level-0">
    <a class="#">Child link</a>
    <ul class="submenu"></ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
var nav_link = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-item-has-children");

for (var i = 0; i < nav_link.length; i++) {
  nav_link[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle('active');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how do I get the javascript to select the child link and attach the click event to that, but still add the active class to the parent `li` item so the CSS cascades through the submenus?

Try this

```
var nav_link = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-item-has-children");

for (var i = 0; i < nav_link.length; i++) {
  nav_link[i].querySelector('a').addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.parentElement.classList.toggle('active');
  });
}
```

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks Alaa. One quick extension question. How might I close all toggle off other items on a parent click (almost radio button style)

Comment: Do you mean if the first link is clicked (first parent li has active class) and then click the second link?

Comment: Yeh, so if I click another parent link, toggle the active class off of all other parent li items

Comment: Edit the code to something like this
`nav_link[i].querySelector('a').addEventListener("click", function () {
        const prevList = document.querySelector('.menu-item-has-children.active');
        if(prevList && prevList !== this.parentElement) prevList.classList.remove('active');
        this.parentElement.classList.toggle('active');
      });`

Comment: If you need an explanation Why do you need the condition? ... before the first click, there'll be no `li` with an active link. Also, each time you toggle the active (close the drop-down), there'll be no `li.active`. The second part is to make sure that the previous `li.active` isn't the parent of the link. Otherwise, it'll remove then add again using the "toggle" (it Will never be removed).

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this as crude solution. Maybe you can implement this using a foreach.
However the issue you are facing is because of event bubbling. You need to stop the click done on sub-menu to propogate to the parent (which is triggering the toggle of active class, therefore, hiding the element.

Add this to your javascript

```
var submenu = document.querySelectorAll(".submenu");

for (var i = 0; i < submenu.length; i++) {
  submenu[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation()
  });
}
```

This solution however, doesn't add/remove active class to submenu, in case you have to expand that. I suggest using a common selector class for doing that

Comment: I tried this, but it had no effect.